# How to speed up this code(Jordan Normal Form)

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I want to calculate the number of unrepeated Jordan canonical forms of n * n matrices consisting of 0 and 1
How to speed up this code

```
sol4=Flatten[Inactive[Table][Table[x[(i-1) 4+j],{i,1,4},{j,1,4}],Sequence@@Table[{x[i],0,1},{i,1,16}]]//Activate,15];GatherBy[sol4,(JordanDecomposition[#1][[2]])&]//Length
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took less than 3 minutes on my Quad Core machine:

```
A = Tuples[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
data = ParallelMap[(JordanDecomposition[#1][[2]]) &, A]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
DeleteDuplicates[data] // Length
```

> 159.48
>
> 395

Comment: How can you speed up if you change it to a 6 * 6 matrix